# correct path for arch linux system /boot/ - x64 laptop uefi machine, GPT partion table

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, uefi, boot-loader

after a rebuild from arch live usb iso, my boot directory is:

[image]

The tree is correct? Or there is a mistake? I know that the system boot up correctly so I should not modify anything, but i need to install the arch system in another machine and I wanted to use the correct path.

uname -r:

```
Linux mymachine 6.7.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon, 05 Feb 2024 22:07:49 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common layout when using GRUB. Note that your EFI System Partition (ESP for short) should be mounted at `/boot/efi` and be part of this layout. The filesystem type of ESP should usually be some form of FAT: FAT32 is the recommended choice to maximize compatibility with old versions of UEFI firmware, although newer versions support other FAT types too.

Most major distributions use this layout with little variation. Usually the name of the `grub` directory on the ESP (`/boot/efi/EFI/grub`) is replaced by the name of the distribution, to allow different operating systems to coexist on the same ESP *as defined in the UEFI specification*:

- `/boot/efi/EFI/debian` for Debian
- `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora` for Fedora
- `/boot/efi/EFI/oracle` for Oracle Linux
- `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat` for RedHat Enterprise Linux
- `/boot/efi/EFI/sles` for SuSE Linux Enterprise Server

However, if you use a different bootloader that can only load kernels from within the ESP the system is booting from, you might instead mount the ESP directly to `/boot` instead of `/boot/efi`. This would make your installed kernel image files (typically `/boot/vmlinuz-<kernel version>`) and initramfs files (typically `/boot/initramfs-<kernel version>`) land directly into the ESP.

In that case, the GRUB-specific `/boot/grub/` directory sub-tree would be left out completely, and might be replaced by other bootloader's specific files or directories, if applicable.

This may require a larger ESP than the one created by default by other operating systems such as Windows 10, so one of the advantages of using GRUB and the layout you described is that it allows the ESP to be quite small even if you're multibooting several Linux distribution and/or Windows off the same ESP.

The Arch Wiki has extensive information on different bootloaders here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_boot_process#Boot_loader